# Web-based complex data-center automation tool

Tags: ant, frameworks, devops, activiti

After evaluating existent tools like Ansible Tower, rundeck and others, it seems that no tool can fulfill the needed requirements.

We have complex data-center servers, cluster of DB and web servers, the data-center has a lot of client-systems, +100, and other tools like solr, redis, kafka... deployed there across the physical servers, not to mention that the same data-center servers have different accounts, linux users, (QA,stag,production..etc), for now the meta-data about these environments alongside their web-apps, source code to be used, servers of the cluster are all defined on xml and there is a bash scriptsreads from that XML that operated manually to run any operation/task (like checkout the source, build, deploy, start, stop... and other customized operations)

This system should be done with a developer and DevOps engineers together, but what I want to know, is there any preferable framework(s) that could be used for this system? does the workflows frameworks are usable on this case? e.g, Activiti BPMN? the Ant is an option but we don't need just an automation tool more that scheduler and logging and a lot of other services.

And if this is not the right place, can you please point out where cat I ask such question?

What's required is to create a web-based system as automation tool with:

- UI to define the specific operations to be done, like build, deploy across the cluster specific web-app on specific env, start/stop specific web-app on specific machine, or any other customized operation, with multiple selections and flexible and dynamic options choosing way.
- The FE should show the executing workflows and operations within them.
- Dynamic way to create set of operations as a single workflow, that have dynamic ability to set the dependencies among them.
- An interface between the back-end code of this system with the already existent bash scripts that will do the actual tasks across the DC servers.
- A scheduler to be able to organize these operations in respect to a defined complicated dependencies between the workflows.
- Authentication & authorization services to the users since there will be a lot of customized roles upon the operations,environments, the products...etc
- Logging system to save the operations outputs.

Comment: This is more of consulting question rather than an actual question with a problem

Comment: No doubt: this is pure dev ops, this need to be scripted, in a surgical way. Don't forget unit tests. If i were this dev, i would do it with php cli, with no framework. Create your own framework.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a combination of ansible/Docker and jenkins, Jenkins can do most of the stuff you described using Pipeline projects/MultiProjects and Ansible for your UI and role related details

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

The task you're describing is basic network orchestration, and there're a bunch of orchestration engines/software out there. However, the fact that you are asking this question means you're just starting out and not ready to invest in a full fledged management product *yet*.

I strongly suggest that you take a look at [Chef](https://docs.chef.io/platform_overview.html) for your purposes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at jenkinsx.io if you are targeting kubernetes and containers (docker). As part of the activiti bpm team we are trying to align with such technologies to make people life easy to integrate more complex workflows with DevOps and operations of your projects.